# Installing Composer on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, bash, iis, iis-7.5, composer-php

I'm trying to install Composer on IIS 7.5. When I run Composer-Setup.exe, it fails with:

> The PHP exe file you specified did not execute correctly:  C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe
>
> Running it from the command line might highlight the problem. Use the
>   -v switch to show the PHP version - it must be at least 5.3.2 Internal Error [ERR_STATUS], exit code 255

I'm using PHP 5.6.9, so then I run the following bash:

```
$ php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
#!/usr/bin/env php 
All settings correct for using Composer
```

There are no errors, but it doesn't download. Using SSL or not makes no difference.

Using cURL gives the same result:

```
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php 
All settings correct for using Composer
```

I'd be grateful for any troubleshooting suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Composer on Windows IIS 7.5 when installer doesn't work:

1. Download the .phar file directly under heading "Manual Download" at https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Create a directory C:\bin and place the .phar file in it.
3. In the same directory as the .phar file create another file called composer.bin (Windows batch file) and insert:

   @ECHO OFF

   SET cwd=%cd%

   PUSHD "C:\bin\PHP"

   SET COMPOSER_HOME=C:\bin

   php "C:\bin\composer.phar" -v --working-dir="%cwd%" %*

   POPD
4. Edit the Windows PATH variable under System Properties ->
   Environment Variables to include the C:\bin\